# View getting blurred occasionally on a specific Android device

Tags: android, performance, android-fragmentactivity

I have come across a problem where the screen of my Android device(Moto G2) gets blurred on click of a specific button in my app. This event happens occasionally and not everytime I click this button. 
This scenario is not happening on few other devices (like LG G3) in which I have tested the app for some time.
I couldnot find anything related or useful in the Logs either.
Just to add, the Log in button which is posing this issue is in a view of a fragment attached.

A screenshot of the scenario :[image]

> Adding code in the Activity's onCreate() where it adds the Fragments :

```
 if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            facebookLoginBtnFragment = new FacebookLoginBtnFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, facebookLoginBtnFragment).commit();
           googleLoginBtnFragment = new GoogleLoginBtnFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container2, googleLoginBtnFragment).commit();

        } else {
            facebookLoginBtnFragment = (FacebookLoginBtnFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
            googleLoginBtnFragment = (GoogleLoginBtnFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container2);
        }
```

> Below is the code of onCreateView() of the  Google + fragment :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gplusloginbtns, container, false);
     gplusButton = (SignInButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.GPlus_Sign_in_button); gplusButton.setOnClickListener(this);
     setGooglePlusButtonText(gplusButton, "Log in with Google");
     rootView.findViewById(R.id.GPlus_sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
     if (mActivity.getClass().toString().contains("ShowProfile_act")) {
         rootView.findViewById(R.id.GPlus_Sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
     } mConnectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());    mConnectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Logging in...");
     return rootView;
 }
```

> Below is the code for setGooglePlusButtonText() method :

```
private void setGooglePlusButtonText(SignInButton signInButton, String buttonText) {
// Find the TextView that is inside of the SignInButton and set its text
        for (int i = 0; i < signInButton.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = signInButton.getChildAt(i);
            if (v instanceof TextView) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) v;
                tv.setText(buttonText);
                return;
            }
        }
}
```

-->The others methods of the fragment deal with connection maintenance part with the Google+ API.I assume they might not be relevant
Any suggestions, advices on the cause and how to avoid such scenarios would be helpful.

Comment: may i see some code behind this?

Comment: @AjayPandya Added some part of the code. I am quite unsure on the cause of this issue and hence on which part of the code may be causing this problem